# NetBeans IDE - Warning

Tags: linux, linux-mint, java, application

I'm using Linux Mint 17.3. I installed NetBeans on it and whenever I open the Netbeans App, I receive this warning message:

> The package containing the class javax.swing.JComponentBeanInfo was
>   not loaded.

Below the warning message are two buttons. One to "Exit" and another to "Disable Modules and Continue.

What is the cause of this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

After this long, I am sure you have sorted this out, but for anyone coming across the same problem, it is due to NetBeans having an issue with the Java platform (JDK).

To fix the issue, add the --jdkhome tag to your launcher.

Right click Menu > Configure... > Open the menu editor > Find your launcher and click Properties. Now edit the command to include something along the lines of:

`./netbeans --jdkhome /usr/lib/jdk1.8.0_73/` (or whatever platform you are using)

Where you previously had `./netbeans` (or something similar)

Comment: Its not clear where to add the above tag, can you please elaborate

Comment: The above tag is added within the launcher command properties. You will find the areas I detailed in my answer when you right click the system menu, which is what I meant with Menu. Within that, you will find the launcher for Netbeans itself. It is there that you will be able to edit the launcher command to include the extra I detailed above.